# Euler's Method in java

Tags: java, arrays, numerical-methods

I have written an Euler's Method code to find an approximate value for x(10) and compare it to the value of x(10) given by the exact solution given in  [separable ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504584/solving-an-ordinary-differential-equation-initial-value-problem).  However, my code displays a chaotic number for x(10).  Can you please identify a major error.

Thank you.

```
 //@(#)euler.java
 //This method attempts to find solutions to dx/dt = (e^t)(sin(x)) via
 //Euler's iterative method and find an approximate value for x(10)


import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class euler
{
    public static void main(String[] Leonhard)
    {

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");


        double h = (1.0/3.0);          // h is the step-size
        double t_0 = 0;                // initial condition
        double x_0 = .3;               // initial condition
        double x_f = 10;               // I want to find x(10) using this method and compare it to an exact value of x(10)
        double[] t_k;
        t_k = new double[ (int)( ( x_f - x_0 ) / h ) + 1 ] ;                 // this two arrays hold the values of x_k and t_k
        double[] x_k;
        x_k = new double[ (int)( ( x_f - x_0 ) / h ) + 1 ] ;

        int i;  // the counter

        System.out.println( "k\t       t_k\t       x_k" ); // table header

        for ( i = 0; k < (int)( ( x_f - x_0 ) / h ) + 1; i++ )
        {
            if ( i == 0 )  // this if statement handles the initial conditions
            {
                t_k[i] = t_0;
                x_k[i] = x_0;
            }
            else if ( i > 0 )
            {
                t_k[i] += i*h;
                x_k[i] = x_k[i-1] + h*( Math.exp(t_k[i-1]))*(Math.sin(x_k[i-1])   );

            }

            System.out.println( k + "      " + df.format(t_k[i])   + "      " +  df.format( x_k[i])  );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @khelwood If by chaotic meaning there are changes when the step-size is changed, then yes.  But is my code correct though, for the ODE that I solved?

Comment: What's `k` in your code?

Comment: @MarcoTompitak, cleared!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? It's expected that step size influences the approximation. What output are you expecting and how does the real output deviate?

Comment: @MarcoTompitak I was expecting something pretty close to PI.  But I realize the step-size DOES influence the approximation.  

Does the code I wrote conform to the Euler's Method algorithm?

Comment: Looks okay! I gave you a more elaborate answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to work. The problem is that Euler's method is a fairly simplistic way of approximately integrating a differential equation. Its accuracy is strongly dependent upon the step size you're using, as you noticed.

I ran your code and compared with another implementation of the same algorithm. The results overlap in the regime where the approximation is working, and quite a while beyond. They only differ once the method breaks down strongly:

[image]

A thing to note is that the Euler method doesn't work very well for this particular differential equation, for the point you wish to reach. A step size of `1/3` is much too big to begin with, but even if you choose a much smaller step size, e.g `1/10000`, the method tends to break down before reaching `t=10`. Something like `exp(t)sin(x)` is hard to deal with. The real solution becomes flat, approaching `pi`, so `sin(x)` should go to zero, making the derivative zero as well. However, `exp(t)` blows up, so the derivative is numerically unstable.

Comment: Hi Marco Tompitak!!! I have a question about the order of accuracy of the backward Euler method. Could you help me? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94006/room-for-evinda-and-marco-tompitak