# Solving Ordinary Differential Equations using Euler in Java Programming

Tags: java, differential-equations

I'm trying to write a java program that will solve any ordinary differential equations using Euler method, but I don't know how to write a code to get any differential equation from the user. I was only able to write the code to solve a predefined ordinary differential equations.

I was able to come with a code to solve some particular ordinary differential equations which were written as functions in the program, I also made research online to look for similar problems but it seem they also wrote it to solve some designated problem not general questions on ordinary differential equations. This was found in most of the article have read online.

Here is my Euler class;

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Euler {
    private double x0, y0, x1, y1, h, actual;

    public Euler (double initialx, double initialy,double stepsize,double finalx1) {  
        x0 = initialx; y0 = initialy; h=stepsize; x1 = finalx1;
    }

    public void setEuler (double initialx, double initialy,double stepsize, 
    double finalx1){
        x0 = initialx;y0 = initialy;h   =stepsize;x1 = finalx1;
    }

    public double getinitialx(){
        return x0;
    }

    public double getinitialy(){
        return y0;
    }

    public double getinitialexact(){
        return (double) (0.9048*Math.exp(0.1*x0*x0));
    }

    double func(double x, double y){
        return (double) (0.2*x*y);
    }

    double funct(double x){
        return (double) (java.lang.Math.exp(0.1*x*x));
    }

    public double getinitialerror(){
        return (double) Math.abs(actual - y0);
    }

    public double getEulerResult(){
        for (double i = x0 + h; i < x1; i += h){
            y0 = y0 + h *(func(x0,y0));
            x0 += h;
            double actual = (0.9048*funct(x0));
            double error = Math.abs(actual - y0);
            System.out.printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",x0,y0,actual, error);
        }
        return y0;
    }

}
```

Here is my Driver's class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EulerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        Euler myEuler = new Euler(1.0,1.0,0.1,1.5);
        System.out.println( "x\t    explicit\tactual\t  error\t    " );

        System.out.printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", myEuler.getinitialx(), 
        myEuler.getinitialy(),myEuler.getinitialexact(),
        myEuler.getinitialerror());

        System.out.printf("my approximated value is %f\n\n", 
        myEuler.getEulerResult ());

        System.out.println("enter another initial value of x: ");
        double initialx = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("enter another initial value of y: ");
        double initialy = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("enter another stepsize value of h: ");
        double stepsize = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.println("enter another upper  bound of x: ");
        double finalx1 = input.nextDouble();

        myEuler.setEuler(initialx,initialy,stepsize,finalx1);
        System.out.println( "x\t    explicit\tactual\t  error\t    " );

        System.out.printf("%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n", myEuler.getinitialx(), 

        myEuler.getinitialy(),myEuler.getinitialexact(),
        myEuler.getinitialerror());

        System.out.printf("my approximated value is %f\n\n", 
        myEuler.getEulerResult ());

    }
}
```

I will be glad if i can en lighted on how to write the java code to collect any ordinary differential equation from the user so as to solve using Euler's method.

Comment: The code you've added in your post can't compile, so at the very least, fix that [so that people can actually see what you see](/help/how-to-ask). With that said, what do you mean with "get[ting] any differential equation from the user"? I don't see any code that even _tries_ to get user input, so have to explained to yourself what form the user's input should even take, or what it should look like?

Comment: thanks @PM 77-1 for the editing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your observations, i mean like a calculator that can solve any quadratic equations of any types- that's what i mean by getting as in any ordinary differential equation without restriction to the only one i have in my code here. am new here and i was told to limit my code, i actually had two classes for the code the driver class is separated form the other class of the ordinary differential equation class.

Comment: i have edited the code to give the full code that works. So please help me out

Comment: An old but rather minimal and self-contained code with this functionality is (currently) found in https://labs.ni.gsu.edu/ashilnikov/software/newphase/, esp. the parser in the expr/ subdirectory. It is improbable that you can parse text strings to functions with much less effort.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ability to compile some code at run time, where part of the code is supplied by the user.

There is a package called JOOR that gives you a Reflect class that contains a compile method. The method takes two parameters (a package name:String and the Java code:String).
I've never personally used it, so can not vouch for its robustness, but here is a tutorial and the javadoc:

https://www.jooq.org/products/jOOR/javadoc/latest/org.jooq.joor/org/joor/Reflect.html#compile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/03/how-to-compile-a-class-at-runtime-with-java-8-and-9/

In your case, you would put your user supplied function in place of the following line of code:

```
return \"Hello World!\";\n"
```

Beware, you need to be 100% absolutely unconditionally guaranteed that the user can only ever enter a function to be solved. If they are supplying code, remember that unless you take safeguards, the code they enter could very easily be code the removes all of the files on your hard drive (or worse).

For the second part of your question - how do i implement a solution in Java using Euler's method, perhaps check out this link: [Euler's Method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467167/eulers-method-in-java) or this https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Euler_method#Java which has it in pretty much every language you can imagine (and probably some you can't).

Comment: No problem, if this works for you, please accept this as the answer.

Comment: thanks sir i will check this out and get back to you,, hopefully this will let me get any ordinary differential equations from the user

Comment: sir i have check the above link out. it is not want am looking for...what am looking for is like writing a program that can solve any quadratic equation taking any quadratic equations from the user...i want the user to be able to solve any ordinary differential equations also using my software..

Comment: No worries. Given your reply, I think you must be asking two questions: 1) How can I accept some input from a user and turn it into a function that I can execute - my answer gives you that.   and 2) How do I implement a solution to an arbitrary equation using the Euler method I've added a link to that effect.

Comment: U mean with the first link sent I can implement it so that the user can input any ordinary differential equations question..? Please if u have any other resources that can make more clear. Please I really need it for my final year school project..

Comment: Thanks sir I really appreciate you sir.. Hope to get more from this site sir

Comment: The first link tells you how to capture input from a user and compile it into Java executable code - this will allow an end user to enter the function. You will still need to wrap it in Java code to make the function a class that can be compiled. **Consider my warning about allowing users to enter code**. The second links to solutions for Euler's method.

Comment: No problem, if this has helped you, can you please accept the answer and upvote it? All the best with your project.

Comment: To upvote,click the little grey triangle that is pointing upwards next to any answer, question or comment. [How to vote - requires 15 reputation points](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)